# Error with XML in a simple WP8 application

Tags: c#, dom, xpath, windows-phone-8

My code is this:

```
namespace MyNSpace
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async private void ButtonParse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            string url = "www.mysite.com";
            string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            HtmlNodeCollection tl = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"photo\"]/a/img");
            //I must still write this part
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error on the `var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();` line:

> The type 'System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Xml.XPath, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,

Why? I read that people got this problem if they didn't load a certain System.Xml.XPath.dll both manually and writing the Using line. If I try to import the DLL manually, I get an error that I'm trying to add a reference to an assembly that is not compatible. It's the first time I'm programming for Windows Phone, so I won't be surprised if it's a little problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added reference to Silverlight version of `System.Xml.XPath.dll`. That's required to use HtmlAgilityPack in Windows Phone Project.

I've tested with Windows Phone 7.5 only, but based on [this article](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HTML_Page_parsing_using_HTMLAgilityPack) it seems to be working for Windows Phone 8 project too (see **Article Metadata** > **Compatibility
Platform(s)** section in that link). In my case the `.dll` resides in this path :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client
```

Comment: If I try to import the DLL manually, I get an error that I'm trying to add a reference to an assembly that is not compatible and the dll is not added.

Comment: windows phone is silverlight based. If you added correct silverlight `.dll` you'll get warning that can be safely ignored, not error.

Comment: So the silverlight dll are not correctly added. What should i add then?

Comment: let me know path to `System.Xml.XPath.dll` in your PC that you just tried to add..

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client

Comment: Use v4.0 instead of v5.0. I tried with v.4.0, brand new windows phone 8 project. It does work.